# excel 2003 need to compare text value from b8 and then text value from m8 then depending on value it calculates out results

Tags: excel, excel-2003

Please forgive me as I have not done any programing in 30 years and I hope my question as phrased in the subject line makes sense.
ok I have the basic equation figured out and working but I do not understand how to have it look at another column and proceed.
 Column `b8` can be any of the following text fields "uta-can" or "uta-acc" or "uta-hrt" or "m-di"
if so then my formula for `S8` is

`=IF(B8="UTA-CAN",O8*3.6,IF(B8="M-DI",O8*3.15,IF(B8="UTA-ACC",O8*3.15,IF(B8="","",IF(B8="UTA-HRT",O8*3.6)))))`

this works.

I now need to check column m8 and if text is "check" then no change is needed

if `m8` is "CC" I need `s8` to calculate `B8` as

`=IF(B8="UTA-CAN",O8*.4*6,IF(B8="M-DI",O8*.4*6,IF(B8="UTA-ACC",O8*.4*6,IF(B8="","",IF(B8="UTA-HRT",O8*.4*6)))))`

if `m8` is "AE" I need `s8` to calculate `B8` as

`=IF(B8="UTA-CAN",O8*.4,IF(B8="M-DI",O8*.4,IF(B8="UTA-ACC",O8*.4,IF(B8="","",IF(B8="UTA-HRT",O8*.4)))))`

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create matrix in any empty space in your workbook and your formula would be much simplier:

```
=IF(B8="","",O8*VLOOKUP(B8,$V$2:$Y$5,1+MATCH(M8,$W$1:$Y$1,0),0))
```

[image]

or if you don't like to create matrix on the sheet, you can create it directly in formula:

```
=IF(B8="","",O8*VLOOKUP(B8,{"uta-can"; 3.6;  2.4; 0.4,
                            "uta-acc"; 3.15; 2.4; 0.4,
                            "uta-hrt"; 3.15; 2.4; 0.4,
                            "m-di";    3.6;  2.4; 0.4
                           },1+MATCH(M8,{"check","CC","AE"},0),0))
```

depending on your local settings you may have some problems with using `;` or `,` in second formula, that's why I include link to the [**test workbook**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsfp9vx5ep002l2/test_simoco.xlsx) (second formula in cell `T8`)